# Cannot install libgfortran3 (unmet dependencies)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I cannot install ligbfortran3. What is the best way to solve this ? I want to keep my install as standard as possible. Thank you.

```
root@arau:~# apt-get --simulate install libgfortran3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@arau:~# 
root@arau:~# 
root@arau:~# 
root@arau:~# 
root@arau:~# aptitude show gcc-4.8-base 
Package: gcc-4.8-base                    
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Version: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
Priority: required
Section: libs
Maintainer: Ubuntu Core developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 222 k
Breaks: dehydra (<= 0.9.hg20110609-2), dehydra (<= 0.9.hg20110609-2), gcc-4.4-base (< 4.4.7), gcc-4.4-base (< 4.4.7), gcc-4.7-base (< 4.7.3),
        gcc-4.7-base (< 4.7.3), gcj-4.4-base (< 4.4.6-9~), gcj-4.4-base (< 4.4.6-9~), gcj-4.6-base (< 4.6.1-4~), gcj-4.6-base (< 4.6.1-4~),
        gnat-4.4-base (< 4.4.6-3~), gnat-4.4-base (< 4.4.6-3~), gnat-4.6 (< 4.6.1-5~), gnat-4.6 (< 4.6.1-5~), gcc-4.8-base (!= 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
Replaces: gcc-4.8-base (< 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)
Description: GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
 This package contains files common to all languages and libraries contained in the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC).
Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/
```

My sources.list is standard:

```
root@arau:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.


## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

------------- EDIT 1

```
root@arau:~# apt-cache policy gcc-4.8-base
gcc-4.8-base:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

------------- EDIT 2

```
root@arau:~# dpkg -l | grep gcc
ii  gcc                                                   4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6                                    amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8                                               4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.8-base:amd64                                    4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.9-base:amd64                                    4.9.1-0ubuntu1                                      amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc-4.8-dev:amd64                                  4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04                                amd64        GCC support library (development files)
ii  libgcc1:amd64                                         1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1                                    amd64        GCC support library
```

------------- EDIT 3

actually "aptitude" solved my problem, thanks guys.

```
root@arau:~# aptitude install libgfortran3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgfortran3{b} 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 250 kB of archives. After unpacking 1 230 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgfortran3 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is installed.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libgfortran3 [Not Installed]                       



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Downgrade the following packages:                                        
1)      cpp-4.8 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]       
2)      gcc-4.8 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]       
3)      gcc-4.8-base [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]  
4)      libasan0 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]      
5)      libatomic1 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]    
6)      libgcc-4.8-dev [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]
7)      libgomp1 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]      
8)      libitm1 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]       
9)      libquadmath0 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]  
10)     libstdc++6 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]    
11)     libtsan0 [4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 (now) -> 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 (trusty)]      



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
```

Comment: Did you run a `sudo apt-get update` before attempting the command?

Comment: yes I did run it. No upgrade though.

Comment: Can you post the output of the following command: `dpkg -l | grep gcc-`

Comment: @harris  you mean dpkg...

Comment: Yes, I meant that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the 3 version?  4.8 is the current one on my trusty system.  If you have an old executable referring to such an old version, try just adding a link to the 4 version.  That might work, unless the old exe is using obsolete functions.

Assuming you really need the 3 library, maybe one way is to install the 32 bit versions to avoid conflict with the 64 bit versions of the library.

Try looking at the still supported 12.04.5 release to see which version it uses, but assume it's at 4 too.  Any release with the 3 fortran as standard will not be currently supported.

You could remove the conflicting package (probably a few), try installing the lib3, see what new complaints are made, delete those, until finally there are no conflicts. Then you would need to supply sources for the required versions, getting messy here, then if you can successfully get things consistent, freeze it so no further updates will happen on those packages.  Certainly not your desired standard install.

The best approach I can see is to treat the lib3 stuff as a cross compiler.  Install what you need locally, and don't touch the regular system.